# Intelligencia.UrlRewriter - using port other than 80

Tags: asp.net, ports, urlrewriter

Does anyone know if it is possible to configure Intelligencia.UrlRewriter to work when accessing a site via a port other than 80?

eg http://mysite.com:70/default.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Are you having a specific problem? This should work if the web server is correctly configured without any changes, unless your hard coding the full path in the rule?

Comment: Yes, I get the following message when trying to access a page known to exist:- 'The page cannot be found'

Answer (score 0):

When writing your re-write rules, use `~/` convention

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Adeel!   

In fact I am rewriting from ASP urls to ASPX urls as follows:-

<rewrite url="/folder1/page1.asp" to="/folder2/page2.aspx?param=1" />

I have tried adding the '~' character to both urls but without success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's IIS you need to configure to listen on port 70; your re-write rules may be fine.